# Magento 2 | Add field to customer edit in adminhtml

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, adminhtml, uicomponent

I want to edit a field to the customer edit in admin html.

[image]

When you look at the picture I want to add a field below "First Name".

I don't want to create a customer attribute, I just want to add a field there.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup**

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
    * @var CustomerSetupFactory
    */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
    * @var AttributeSetFactory
    */
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    /**
    * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /*customersetupfactory instead of eavsetupfactory */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        // for remove attribute
        //$customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,'address_book');

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        /* create customer Address book attribute */



        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
        Customer::ENTITY,'address_book', 
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar', // attribute with varchar type
                    'label' => 'Address Book',
                    'input' => 'text', // attribute input field is text
                    'required' => false, // field is not required
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position' => 50,
                    'sort_order' => 50,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => 1, //setting grid options
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1,
                ]
            );
        $sampleAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'address_book')
            ->addData(
                [
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'],
                ]
            // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
            );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

> Before Run setup Upgrade command please delete you module entry form **setup_module** table and if attribute is already then uncomment  remove line and remove addAttribute code.  If it's not set proper position then change position and sort_order number.

***I Hope This Helps You.***